# Change the default music player in google assistant sdk

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

Is there a way to change the default music player in the google assistant sdk. Should I try using IFTTT or is there a better way? For refernce I am running it on a raspberry pi 3.

Comment: The Google Assistant SDK does not come with a music player, and note that playing music is [not currently supported](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/release-notes). Can you elaborate on what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I cannot comment... But I had the same issue. To clarify, as I understand it, while Google Assistant SDK cannot play music on itself, it can tell a Chromecast or Chromecast audio to play Netflix or music. You can say "play classical music on living room" and it will tell you that a default music player needs to be set on the Google home app. Unfortunately the instructions for this process - https://support.google.com/googlehome/answer/7030379?hl=en do not work. I have concluded that these instructions only work if you have a Google home since the menu options they outline cannot be found in my

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [a teardown of the latest Google Home app apk](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-home-v2-3-prepares-to-add-cloud-device-casting-support-for-3rd-party-assistant-speakers-listing-reminders-and-much-more/), devices using the Google Home SDK will soon be able to be controled via the Google Home app.

Untill that's released however, and I know it's a mouthful, you can say

> Cast ***song*** by ***artist*** from ***music provider*** to ***chromecast name***

For example

> Cast Creep by Radiohead from Google Play Music to The Living Room Chromecast